# cURL - How to loop a task for multiple websites?

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL script and I'm using it to update my web directory. I know that I can use RSS feeds (more friendly?) etc, but because this is my first script ever I would like to add a new features to it so I can improve my PHP skills:)

Currenly my script is using cURL to:

1. Login to admin panel [POST]
2. Create a backup of existing page [POST]
3. Update existing page with new content [POST]

**Login**:

```
$username="username";
$password="admin";
$url="http://domain.com";
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$postdata (...)
```

All cURLS are using same name: $ch = curl_init(); e.g.

Login:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt (...)
```

Then backup

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt (...)
```

Then update

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt (...)
```

etc.

I just installed two new web directories and would like to use my cURL script to update both in the same way. I know that I can copy all **curl_inits** and just change URLs but I can not imagine doing this if I have 10 new directories :)

My question is: how i can create a loop so my cuRL will:

1. Login -> backup page -> update page using http://domain1.com
2. Login -> backup page -> update page using http://domain2.com
3. Login -> backup page -> update page using http://domain3.com
4. Stop the loop when the last url has been processed.

I'm new into PHP so please be patient :) 
Cheers!

Comment: your own site? i don't really see why you would need to login via curl. you should have complete acess anyway

Comment: make a multi dimensional array and loop it.

Comment: New to PHP or new to programming? Most languages have arrays, the general idea is independent of the language.

Comment: In order to reject, ban or approve new listings in the back end, I need to login first and do it manually. With 3+ it's going to be a pain to verify all, so I prefer to use one copy of approved listings that I can post at once to all of my sites. This script is not using DB just PHP and text files :)

Comment: Thanks laec-hOne :) http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp @Barmar I'm new to programming with a little bit of experience in css :)

Comment: I wish people would just say that right out. "I'm new to PHP" sounds like "I know C (and/or C++, Javascript, Fortran, whatever), but I'm still learning PHP."

Comment: @Barmar I see your point, my fault :)

Comment: You're not the first, won't be the last. I'm just grumbling. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a multi dimensional array and loop through it.

```
<?php
$postdata = array('Your update info ect');


$sites = array(

         array('url'=>'http://siteA.com',
               'username'=>'username',
               'password'=>'admin',
               'cookie'=>"cookie.txt",
               'postdata'=>$postdata),

         array('url'=>'http://siteB.com',
               'username'=>'username',
               'password'=>'admin',
               'cookie'=>"cookie.txt",
               'postdata'=>$postdata),

         array('url'=>'http://siteC.com',
               'username'=>'username',
               'password'=>'admin',
               'cookie'=>"cookie.txt",
               'postdata'=>$postdata),
); 

foreach($sites as $site){
    /*
    $site contains
    Array
        (
            $site['url'] => http://site*.com
            $site['username'] => username
            $site['password'] => admin
            $site['cookie'] => cookie.txt
            $site['postdata'] => Array
                                (
                                    Your update info ect
                                )
        )
    */

    //Do code for:
    //Login
    //Backup page
    //Update page
}
?>
```

Comment: no probs, there are easier ways todo it though, you could make an updater XML file, use CRON on your sites to visit and parse the file into your dbs.